# What is the temperature of empty space if a spaceship is travelling at half the speed of light?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, temperature, interstellar-matter, interstellar-travel

Whenever someone talks about sending robots to extra-solar planets by accelerating them close to the speed of light (perhaps using lasers) - for example I believe Hawking suggested this. It always occurs to me that they will be travelling through a very sparse gas of hydrogen (1 atom per cubic centimetre).

For a slow spaceship this would be essentially a vacuum, but for a spaceship travelling at, say 0.5c, it would feel like billions of hydrogen atoms hitting the spaceship at velocities of 0.5c.

Assuming that the spaceship can withstand 3000 degrees F. I wonder if a spaceship would simply melt when travelling at 0.5c due to collisions with hydrogen atoms.

I find it strange that this issue never seems to be talked about in popular articles about interstellar travel. Perhaps it is not a big issue as I made out?

Anyway, my question is: What temperature and force would the spaceship experience when travelling at 0.5c in interstellar space due to the sparse hydrogen atoms in empty space?

Comment: The heating issue is discussed in Hoang et al.'s "[The Interaction of Relativistic Spacecrafts with the Interstellar Medium](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aa5da6)." The heating occurs not because the medium has an intrinsically high temperature but because its relative bulk motion is large, producing a large [stagnation temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature).

Comment: This answer calculates that the friction due to the interstellar medium is low at 0.5c. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29970/123208 At high speeds, where time dilation becomes useful, the friction is significant. And you also have to worry about the blue-shifted CMBR & cosmic rays.